# Detecting a .NET exception in PS

Tags: powershell

I am making several calls to .NET classes in order in my PS script like this:

```
[class1]::MethodA()
[class1]::MethodB()

if(/*check if last method threw an error*/)
{
    "MethodB failed! Exiting."
    return
}

[class2]::MethodC()
[class2]::MethodD()
```

I really want to check whether there was an exception from MethodB before moving on.  How do check for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a try/catch block:

```
try
{
 [class1]::MethodB()
}
catch
{
 Write-Host "MethodB failed!"
 exit
}
```